# Current directory and parent directory seem broken

Tags: shell, command-line, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 and I have a strange problem.

When I launch a Command Terminal, it seems that current directory and parent directory don't work when I try to use it to launch executable.

For example, considering the following folders :

```
C:/dirA/dirB/program.exe
C:/dirA/dirB/dirC
```

I put dirA/dirB in the PATH variable.

So, when I launch program.exe in Command Terminal, it works.

But, if I go in C:/ and launch the following command :

```
./dirA/dirB/program.exe
```

I got the following error :

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Error is the same if I go on C:/dirA/dirB/dirC folder and launch the following command :

```
../program.exe
```

Error is :

> '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

So, I don't understand what is the problem and how to solve it. Someone have an idea and can help me ?

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use forward slashes (/) with paths in Windows Command Prompt you need to quote the whole path.

```
"./dirA/dirB/program.exe"
```

If you use backslashes (\) then you don't have to quote paths (unless your path contains spaces).